# Deploying a jar artifact to Nexus results in a content type mismatch

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, nexus

I am using Nexus Repository Manager v3.1.0-04. When I attempt to `mvn deploy` a jar artifact to my repository, I get the following problem.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.5.1:deploy
>   (injected-nexus-deploy) on project rest-service: Failed to deploy
>   artifacts: Could not transfer artifact
>   com.xyz:rest-service:jar:0.0.1-20180504.193415-6 from/to nexus
>   (http://nexus.mydomain.io/repository/snapshots/): Failed to transfer
>   file:
>   http://nexus.mydomain.io/repository/snapshots/com/xyz/rest-service/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest-service-0.0.1-20180504.193415-6.jar.
>   Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Detected content type
>   [application/x-sh], but expected [application/java-archive]:
>   com/xyz/rest-service/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest-service-0.0.1-20180504.193415-6.jar.
>   -> [Help 1]

I thought that maybe this was related to the version of `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` ([link](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin)) but even if I set the version to `1.6.8` (latest), I get the same effect. This [post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9437) suggest that to use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`, and so I modified my `pom.xml` as follows.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifacts>
            <artifact>
                <file>target/${artifactId}-${version}.jar</file>
                <type>jar</type>
            </artifact>
            </artifacts>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, I see a different problem now.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:attach-artifact
>   (attach-artifacts) on project rest-service: Execution attach-artifacts
>   of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:attach-artifact
>   failed: For artifact {com.xyz:rest-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:jar}: An
>   attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main
>   artifact. -> [Help 1]

Note that the Maven project is generated by Spring Initializer via IntelliJ and is a Spring Boot project. Without using the [Builder Helper](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin, I can see that all files are successfully uploaded to Nexus until the jar is finished uploaded (it actually finishes uploaded, but because the content type mismatches, it fails).

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? The post I mentioned says "some maven repositories check the file content," and so, how would I disable Nexus (which I have control over) in checking file content? But the real problem is, why is the content type `application/x-sh` instead of `application/java-archive`?

Comment: Why are you using the build-helper-plugin ?

Comment: I'm not using it. The closest thing I've got in searching on the internet suggested to use it, but it creates its own problems. I've removed it from my pom.xml.

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade your Nexus manager cause in the mean time version 3.11 exists..and there are many bug fixes...

Comment: FYI: Problem still exists with 3.11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the settings of the repository in question (the URL in the the error message mentions the "Snapshots" repository), **Storage** section: disable the **Strict content type validation** setting. The description of that setting is: `Validate that all content uploaded to this repository is of a MIME type appropriate for the repository format`.

To answer the second question, why: load the JAR file in an editor. You might see a shell script header (Bash). In that case the JAR file is a "executable JAR", and the shell script header is a startup script from Spring Boot. Because of this Nexus wrongly detects the file as being a shell script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#    .   ____          _            __ _ _
#   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
#  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
#   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
#    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
#   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
#   :: Spring Boot Startup Script ::
#
# ... etc
```

Here a screenshot of such a file opened in Sublime Text:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Ironic thing is that when I inspect the jar artifact, the content-type on the UI shows as `application/java-archive`.

Comment: Yes, because the type shown is the type `declared` at upload by Maven (btw., "jar" is the default type), not the `real` or `detected` type. :-)